# Interactive Traffic Lights on Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I am new Arduino and am trying to build interactive traffic light. This code is failing to compile. Please help.

```
int rPin = 12; 
int yPin = 11;
int gPin = 10;
int r1Pin = 9;
int g2Pin = 8; 
int button = 2; 
int crossTime = 5000; 
unsigned long changeTime;

void setup ()
{ 
    pinMode ( rPin, OUTPUT ); 
    pinMode ( yPin, OUTPUT );
    pinMode ( gPin, OUTPUT );
    pinMode ( r1Pin , OUTPUT );
    pinMode ( g2Pin, OUTPUT ); 
    pinMode ( button , INPUT );
    digitalWrite ( gPin ,HIGH) ;
    digitalWrite ( r1Pin , HIGH); 
 }

void loop()
{ 
    int state = digitalRead ( button);
    if (state == HIGH && ( millis() - changetime ) > 5000))
    {
        changeLights();
    }
}

void chngeLight()
{ 
    digitalWrite ( gPin , LOW );
    digitalWrite ( yPin, HIGH ); 
    delay ( 2000); 

    digitalWrite ( yPin, LOW );
    digitalWrite ( rPin , HIGH ); 
    delay(crossTime) ; 

    for ( int x=0; x<10 , x++); 
    { 
        digitalWrite ( g2Pin , HIGH );
        delay ( 250);

        digitalWrite ( g2Pin , LOW );
        delay ( 250);
    }

    digitalWrite ( g2Pin , HIGH );
    delay (500) ; 

    digitalWrite ( yPin , HIGH );
    digitalWrite ( rPin , LOW );
    delay ( 2000);

    digitalWrite ( yPin , LOW );
    digitalWrite ( gPin , HIGH ); 

    changeTime = millis ();
}
```

My only problem is in the void loop. The Arduino compiler is not accepting *changeLights* as a function. So I created a new *unsigned long* called "changeLights", but it still doesn't work.

[Here is the link to screenshot of the image](http://postimg.org/image/jgqicozh9/).

Comment: `So i created a new unsigned long called "changeLights"` -- Why would you do that?  It seems like you want to call chngeLight(), but are calling the non-existent function changeLights() instead.  Don't guess; if you don't understand something in programming, figure it out logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have trouble compiling something, please include the output and error messages from the compiler.

You have some syntax and related errors in your code.

```
for ( int x=0; x<10 , x++);
```

A 'for' statement with a semicolon directly after it means it has no body. Since you had a block of code after the for statement, I don't think this is what you intended. Delete the ';' at the end.  Also, the , and ; are distinct operators, they do different things. Replace the ',' with a ';'.

```
if (state == HIGH && ( millis() - changetime ) > 5000))
```

This statement has unbalanced parentheses: 3 right parens and 4 left parens.  It won't compile.  Even if it did, it wouldn't do what you want.
Try:

```
if ((state == HIGH) && ((millis() - changetime) > 5000))
```

The function you define `chngeLight` does not match the function you called `changeLights`.
The names need to match, or the compiler thinks they are different functions.

Answer (score 0):

You declare your function as

```
void chngeLight()
```

but you call it with

```
changeLights()
```

(Notice one has an "s" and the other doesn't). Try changing your call to changeLight() and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**

First off your changeLights Method is misspelled.

Second, in C++ you need to either [create a prototype](http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html)

OR

put the method that you want to call above the actual call.

**Details:**

To create a prototype for your `ChangeLights()` method

place the cursor above the `setup()` method and put this in

```
void ChangeLights();
```

This is going to tell the rest of your file that this method call exists and that it doesn't take any arguments or return anything.

The other way to do this is to physically move your ChangeLights() method above the method(s) where you call it. This is a little more ghetto and not the prefered way.